# Django static file with custom filename?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Here's my code:

```
{% for activity in activities %}
            <div id="div_{{ forloop.counter }}" class="scrollTo divs">
                <video autoplay  poster="{% static '{{ activity.image }}' %}" loop>
                    <source src="{% static '{{ activity.video_web }}' %}">
                    <source src="{% static '{{ activity.video_mp4 }}' %}" type="video/mp4">
                </video>
                <h1 id="div_{{ forloop.counter }}" class="titles">{{ activity.description }}</h1>
                <h3 class="descriptions">{{ activity.second_description }}</h3>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
```

The thing is, `'{{ activity.image }}'` is taken literally and that's the value it gets in the final html. How can I make it give the actual value of `activity.image` etc?

Comment: Replacing `{% static '{{ activity.image }}' %}` with `{{activity.image.url}}` would work for you?

Comment: activity.image is just the name of the image...

Comment: {% static activity.image %} works?

Comment: Is the image definitely a static asset? How will it know which folder to look in to find it? You will probably be better off storing the Image as an `ImageField` since your database will get erroneous data if you ever decide to move/delete the asset

Comment: {% static activity.image %} doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as `activity.image` is a string, You can just type:

```
{% static activity.image %}
```

The `{{ }}` brackets just for printing the variable into your document. Inside a `{% %}` tag you can simply use the variable name, without additional brackets.

if `activity.image` is a `FileField`, then this is not the way to serve it. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/files/#using-files-in-models for more details.

Comment: All of these are simple CharFields with the name of the image/video etc.

Comment: I get: Reverse for 'images/Beach.png' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Comment: Sorry, my bad I ment `static`, not `url`. I'm editing the answer now.